# SCRIPT5002: Function expected when copying an array [...files]

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

I have an `<input type="file" id="photos" multiple>`.

When I upload some image I have the code below:

```
$('#photos').change(function() {
    previewUpload({
        this: this,
    });
}, false);
```

and in the previewUpload I try to copy the files from this, like this:

```
const previewUpload = function(conf){
    const files = [...conf.this.files];
    console.log(files);
}
```

But when I try to use this function on Edge, the browser returns me SCRIPT5002: Function expected on this line:

```
const files = [...conf.this.files];
```

Any solution?

- The problem is when I try to get the files from input

Comment: Are you trying to access `this` context inside `conf`? You can't do that.

Comment: I send the `element` in `this`, in Chrome works and never displayed an error. So, how I send the input inside the object `conf`?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue according to your code, but I did not see the error and the previewUpload is nowhere to see. Could you share your code more in detail?

Comment: Did you try using the IE Edge? @JeniferJiang.

I can solve this problem replacing 
`const files = [...conf.this.files]` to `const files = Object.values(conf.this.files)`;

Comment: FYI IE is a different browser from Edge. There's no such thing as an "IE Edge" browser.

Comment: "function expected" probably means that `conf.this.files` is not *iterable*.